# After deploying I need to refresh server for changes to reflect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, symlink

I'm deploying a rails app using a service which uses a symblink method with current/release folders on Ubuntu 14.04. However every time I deploy I have to refresh the server in order to see changes reflected by running:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

If I do a standard FTP deploy without any symblinks I can see the changes immediately. Is there anyway around refreshing the server in order in order for the updates to reflect?

Thanks